# We are using Spring Cloud Stream for Kafka and we are looking for Exactly Once Semantics with consumer API

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Spring Cloud Stream for Kafka and looking for Exactly Once Semantics. 
We have one solution which is working fine as expected 
1) Enabling Idempotent & Transaction from producer
2) Using MetaDataStore to check the duplicate message from consumer side with key (offsetId + partitionId + topicName)
With the above solution we are not having any message loss & no duplicate processing

But now we found there's one property (`producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction`) Kafka API which is helping us to fix the duplicate processing from consumer side without any metadatastore logic. Now am not sure how we can do that with spring cloud stream with this property `.sendOffsetsToTransaction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's handled by the framework automatically if you add a `KafkaTransactionManager` to the application context.

You have to add a transaction id prefix to the configuration.

`spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix`

and Boot will automatically add a transaction manager.

See [producer properties](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties).

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix`
>
> Enables transactions in the binder. See transaction.id in the Kafka documentation and Transactions in the spring-kafka documentation. When transactions are enabled, individual producer properties are ignored and all producers use the spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.* properties.

The listener container sends the offset to the transaction before committing the transaction when the listener exits normally.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gary. So If I have this property(  kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix:) enabled in application.yml
  
It will create transactionmanager, which intern will take care of calling this method and passing the value (offsets & groupId's) to 'sendOffsetsToTransaction' right?.

Comment: No; you either need to manually configure a transaction manager, or you need to also set the Boot `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix` property so that he will declare the transaction manager for you. Then, the container will automatically send the offsets for you.

Comment: Gary, thanks for your replay am able to make that change and it's working fine. But I have different scenario and am seeing different behavior. Like total of 3 different services 
1) First service will listen from Solace queue and produce it to kafka topic-1 (where transaction are enabled) 2) Second Service will listen from above kafka topic-1 and write it to another kafka topic-2 (where we have no manual commits, transactions enabled to produce to other topic, auto commit offset as false & isolation.level is set to read_commited)

Comment: 3) Third Service will listen from kafka topic-2 and write it back to Solace queue (where we have no manual commits, auto commit offset as false & isolation.level is set to read_commited). Now the issue after I enabled transaction and isolation level at the second service am not able to read any messages, if I disabled the transaction in second service am able to read all the messages. 1) Can we have transactions enabled & isolation level in one single service 
2) How it works if my service is just a producer or consumer (how EoS guaranteed for these services)

Comment: `>and it's working fine...`. Comments aren't designed for asking additional questions; you should close this one out and start a new one.

Comment: the same solution is not working for other scenario (when my service is acting as producer  & consumer). But I can put it as new question

Comment: Right - it's too hard to read all running together like that.